# How to ensure that a long running method is not executed in parallel by multiple tasks?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a basic Dictionary based cache in a class.

```
private HashSet<string> _myCache = new HashSet<string>();

private void BuildMyCache()
        {
          
           lock(_cacheLock)
            {

                try
                {
                    _cacheRebuildInProgress = true;
                    _favouritesCache.Clear();
                    //Populate the _myCache hashset here by querying the database
                                              
                        }
                    }
                    _cacheRebuildInProgress = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _cacheRebuildInProgress = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

and then I have this method in the same class which may be called by multiple tasks, all running at the same time.

```
public bool ValueExistsInMyCache(string valueToSearch)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if(!_cacheRebuildInProgress)
                {
                    if (_myCache.Count == 0 || stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 / 60 >= _cacheSettings.TimespanMinutes)
                    {
                        BuildMyCache();
                        stopWatch.Restart();                       
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                
            }
           
            var result = _myCache.Contains(valueToSearch);
            return result;
        }
```

So the way I see this working ideally is:

1- Multiple tasks might try to read from my cache at the same time. That's **fine**

2- If the cache is being rebuilt, I'd like the rebuild method to be called **only once**, making any subsequent task to wait while it is rebuilt and then search the cache that was rebuilt

The question is, does the above code accomplish 2, and also I should consider using a  caching library for this simple use case and save myself the headache of having to deal with hard to debug situations later because I might get how I've written this wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Imho you should use something thread safe for your cache. Something like ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentDictionary. With this you have refactored away your thread safety concerns.
Then you should keep an eye on who does what. If there is a method that builds a cache, just let it do it. It should not be blocked by something.
Is something reading from the cache? Dont make it fail, just expect the case that it is empty and build a retry mechanism.
And please do not use while(true)

Comment: Sounds like a case for a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`?

Comment: Is the (nonstatic?) field `_cacheRebuildInProgress` marked as `volatile`?

Comment: Your code does not prevent the following: One thread gets past the `while` loop and goes into the `Contains` method where it starts to figure out what the hash code is and what bucket to look in. At the same time another thread sees that cache is old, sees that the lock is not held, and starts `.Clear()` followed by repopulating of the `HashSet<>`. So it does not seem quite safe enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=net-6.0).

```
if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref myField, 1, 0) == 0){

}
```

That should ensure that only one caller succeeds in the check, and all other fail. If you want to run the check multiple times you obviously need to reset the field, and using lock or memoryBarrier to ensure the write is not moved around by the compiler or CPU.

Also note that `HashSet<string>` is not thread safe, so if there is any chance of concurrent access (with exception of concurrent reads), *all* accesses need to be inside a lock, or possibly some other synchronization mechanism. The posted example code looks unsafe to me. A [concurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0) might be a much safer option to use. That sleep also looks like a poor design, if some other thread is updating the cache it might be a better option to wait for that to be done using some kind of [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a read/write lock. You allow multiple readers at the same time, but you only want to allow one writer (the thing rebuilding the cache) at a time, and the writer can't operate while any of the readers are reading.

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _myCacheLock = new();
private readonly HashSet<string> _myCache = new HashSet<string>();

private void BuildMyCache()
{
    _myCacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        _myCache.Clear();
        //Populate the _myCache hashset here by querying the database
    }
    finally
    {
        _myCacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

public bool ValueExistsInMyCache(string valueToSearch)
{
    _myCacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        return _myCache.Contains(valueToSearch);
    }
    finally
    {
        _myCacheLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

That said, it might be easier to built a new cache into a *new* `HashSet<string>`, and only write that to `_myCache` when it's done. This has the advantage that readers aren't blocked while a new cache is being rebuilt: they'll just continue using the old cache until the new one is ready.

You'll still need a lock around reads/writes of the `_myCache` field as reading threads are allowed to simply ignore changes to this field otherwise.

```
private readonly object _myCacheLock = new();
private HashSet<string> _myCache = new HashSet<string>();

private void BuildMyCache()
{
    var newCache = new HashSet<string>();
    // Populate newCache here by querying the database
    lock (_myCacheLock)
    {
        _myCache = newCache;
    }
}

public bool ValueExistsInMyCache(string valueToSearch)
{
    HashSet<string> myCache;
    lock (_myCacheLock)
    {
        myCache = _myCache;
    }
    return myCache.Contains(valueToSearch);
}
```

Note that this approach won't stop multiple concurrent calls to `BuildMyCache` from all building the cache in parallel. This is "safe", but probably wasteful if this is likely to happen.

Comment: Upvoted, very good answer. Are you sure the `lock` is really necessary in your second solution (switching to a new instance of `HashSet<>` each time the cache is rebuilt)? Moving a reference from one instance to another instance should be thread-safe enough? If you are afraid some thread will not realize that it needs to re-read the reference of the `_myCache` fields, will the presence of the `lock` construct make it aware of that? I have heard you could say "`volatile`", i.e. `private volatile HashSet<string> _myCache`, to make the runtime more aware that the reference could need a re-read.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen "*Moving a reference from one instance to another instance should be thread-safe enough?*" -- it won't tear, but there's no guarantee that the reading thread will read the updated field value. The JIT is allowed to move reads arbitarily backwards in time (e.g. if the field is read in a tight loop, it might move the read before the loop entirely). The CPU is allowed to move reads around as well. Caches get in the way: a write from one CPU core might write to a core-local cache, but the CPU is not obliged to propagate that to other cores' caches in a timely manner

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You need a memory barrier to force the runtime and CPU to propagate the new field write to all readers, and to force all readers to read the new value. The easiest way to get a memory barrier is with a `lock`. The semantics of `volatile` are very complex and poorly understood, and the guys who develop the runtime recommend against using it. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/12/can-i-skip-the-lock-when-reading-an-integer/) and the follow-up linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What you've created yourself is a spinlock with an expiring cache. The latter is what the other answers seem to have not taken into account.

You may get your solution to work but it's probably not going to be the most performant or stable and it's best to not reinvent the wheel in general.

Have a look at [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) - this will conduct the expiry time for you.
You will have to add Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions and Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory nuget packages.
Unfortunately, you will have to do your own locking to avoid multiple threads populating the cache in parallel.

```
    private static object locker = new object();

    public bool ValueExistsInMyCache(string valueToSearch)
    {
        string cacheKey = "myCache";

        bool? checkCache()
        {
            var hashSet = cache.Get<HashSet<string>>(cacheKey);
            if (hashSet != null)
                return hashSet.Contains(valueToSearch);
            return null;
        }

        var result = checkCache();
        if (result != null)
            return result.Value;

        lock (locker)
        {
            result = checkCache();
            if (result != null)
                return result.Value;
            var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
            //populateHashset here
            result = hashSet.Contains(valueToSearch);
            cache.Set(cacheKey, hashSet, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_cacheSettings.TimespanMinutes)));
        }

        return result.Value;
    }
```

The above code is a quick example - you could further refactor it to not need the hashSet anymore but I'll leave that up to you :-)

Comment: Note that if you have lots of concurrent calls to `ValueExistsInMyCache`, they can all decide that `myCache` has expired at the same time, and they'll all end up populating their own versions of `hashSet` in parallel

Comment: @canton7 You are right - I was under the impression that this extension was thread safe but apparently I was mistaken.